# Is it possible to do single login for fb and fb invite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I did a fb login for my app it is working fine ,i added code below what i used for login

```
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

     }];
```

This is working fine after login i have enabled the FBinvite but again it is asking for login this is my FBinvite code

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
                 content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
                 content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.wine.my/media/wysiwyg/icotheme/puro/logo/logo_4.png"];
                 [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self
                                                  withContent:content
                                                     delegate:self];
```

So if user logged in through fb already then i need to stop asking login again when user clicks invite ,is it possible ?

Comment: you can do it..

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik bro can you show me the way

Comment: call this  `FBSDKAppInviteContent`function inside `handler`

Comment: but inside FBSDKAppInviteContent class there is no method bro @Anbu.Karthik